# Why do I keep getting COM exception when using FormulaArray

Tags: c#, excel, exception, com-interop, array-formulas

```
try
{
    sheet1.get_Range("M34").FormulaArray =
    "=SUM(IF(Sheet2!D6:D122=M31,IF(Sheet2!P6:P122>0,Sheet2!I6:I122/SUMIFS(Sheet2!I:I,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!C6:C122,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!D6:D122)*ROUNDUP(SUMIFS(Sheet2!I:I,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!C6:C122,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!D6:D122)/Sheet2!Q3,0),0),0))";
}
catch (COMException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

Anyone know why the above code throws a COM exception. The formula works fine if i enter into excel and press ctrl+shift+enter but when having my program write to excel it throws an exception. I used Range.FormulaArray elsewhere in my program and it worked fine. Maybe someone can point out the problem because I am going crazy and it seems others are having the same problem but no solutions online.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)"

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the expression?

Comment: well i can figure it out using multiple cells but I wanted the calculation in one cell for a cleaner presentation, i wish i could simplify it but don't think i can unless i do the math behind the scenes but i prefer it to be calculated in excel, should i delete the tags or change title?

Comment: i reviewed the rules link u sent but i think it means if i make my entire title something like "Excel Interop" but im using the tags in the context of a question, well if a moderator says something I will change but i think im ok

Comment: Maybe I need to set my range to a variable like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range; and write range.FormulaArray so I avoid using two dots which i heard is bad to do with COM objects

Comment: No, I mean simplify the formula. Try the simplest possible formula and see if that works. If it works, then the problem was specific to the formula. If it doesn't work, then the problem was with the technique, and you would have had the same problem with _any_ formula.

Comment: Also, FYI, don't display ex.Message. Display ex.ToString().

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip on the Exception message, I will keep that in mind, and yes I simplified into two statements as Rory suggested below and turns out my formula was the issue, i just wish i can do all in one cell without doing anything behind the scenes, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this work around and it worked.

```
try        
{  
sheet1.get_Range("M33").FormulaArray = "=SUMIFS(Sheet2!I:I,Sheet2!C:C,Sheet2!C6:C122,Sheet2!D:D,Sheet2!D6:D122)";

sheet1.get_Range("M34").FormulaArray = "=SUM(IF(Sheet2!D6:D122=M31,IF(Sheet2!P6:P122>0,Sheet2!I6:I122/Sheet1!M33*ROUNDUP(Sheet1!M33/Sheet2!Q3,0),0),0))";        
}        
catch (COMException ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString); }
```

Comment: Ahh ok Ill give that a try now

Comment: Well your suggestion fixed it :) but now I have a cell with a value I would prefer to hide, wish I knew why this works but not written as one statement, anyways MUCH APPRECIATED :)